# Using Nonstop SQL with C#

Tags: c#, hp-nonstop

Is there a way to connect to a HP Nonstop SQL database and perform CRUD operations from a C# based web application?

I have done some research on this and identified that Nonstop SQL can be accessed through ODBC drivers. However, there is clear answer on weather it can be used the same way as we do it for other Databases. Please let me know if someone has implemented a C#-Nonstop SQL architecture before.

Comment: I would expect that if ODBC can be used with Nonstop SQL, then you would use it the same way you'd use ODBC with any other data store.  Have you tried a few lines of code to see if works?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have not tried out any implementation as yet. I am still deciding if this is a feasible architecture and was looking for someone who has already done it. If not, I will resort to trial and error myself to figure out if it works and how.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC for the NonStop databases works like... ODBC, so you should have no problem from an architecture perspective.

Note that there are two distinct implementations of SQL on the NonStop SQL/MP and SQL/MX, make sure that you have the documentation for the correct one. SQL/MP is probably more common, but less standard.